# Altium Pad Net names vertically mirrored

Tags: altium

I'm trying to make a printout of a PCB design, showing the net names each component pad is connected to. I'm running into a problem though -- after I enable the option to show these net names, the displayed names are all mirrored vertically: [image]

I've tried setting the printout to be mirrored, but that just mirrors everything horizontally (not vertically), so the problem remains. Does anybody know how to correct this?

Comment: Which side of the board are you looking at?

Comment: The image I posted is for top-side, but the same thing happens for a bottom side view. Also, the component on the left is on the bottom side, the one on the right is on the top side

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I see it's from 2018, but I'm having the same issue with AD 22, and feel like it must have been something obvious that I'm missing... If you found a solution, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: For the new guy from 2022: I would say, check the import options that you are using.I recommend to generate an output jobs instead of trying to do it manually, it's less prone to error. I will try tomorrow with at the job to see if there's an option to flip-it and expand the answer